# Finding the solution of a differential equation that passes through a point

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How could I find a solution to the differential equation

$$x\frac{dy}{dx}=y^2-y$$

that passes through the point $y=(1/2,1/2)$
and write it in terms of $y$ ?

What I have attempted: I rewrote the differential equation into the form

$$\frac{1}{y^2-y}dy=\frac{1}{x}dx$$

and then integrated it

$$\int \frac{dy}{y^2-y}=\frac{1}{x}dx,$$

getting $$\ln\frac{y-1}{y}=\ln(x).$$

$$e^{ln((y-1)/y)}=e^{ln(x)}+c$$

$$\frac{y-1}{y}=x+c$$

$$y-1=xy+cy$$

$$y-1=y(x+c)$$

But now how can we make pass it through $(1/2,1/2)$ in terms of $y$ ?

Comment: You are almost there! There is only one value of $c$ which makes $(1/2,1/2)$ a solution to the equation.

Comment: The step $\frac{y-1}{y}=x+c$ is faulty, actually $\log\frac{y-1}{y}=\log(x)+c$ hence $\frac{y(x)-1}{y(x)}=cx$. Can you finish now? You know that $y(1/2)=1/2$, this gives you $c$...

Comment: @I did not notice it is faulty let me see

Comment: I got $c=-2$ But how would

Comment: So then would I got $\frac{y(x)-1}{y(x)}=-2x$

Comment: So then would would this be $1-\frac{1}{y(x)}=-2x$

Comment: Yes, $y(x)=\frac1{1+2x}$.

Answer (score 1):

Put $(x=\frac{1}{2},y=\frac{1}{2})$ in the equation you have obtained and find the value of the integration constant $c$. That will serve your problem. As much as I see it, the value of $c$ will come out to be $-\frac{3}{2}$.